# Is there a way to improve kivy's drawing capabilities?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, kivy

I decided to go with kivy at work to create a minimal viable product for a project.
I love the general workflow with kivy, it is simple and expressive.
however, when I use the widgets' canvas to draw shapes, it seems to render curves and diagonal lines in a very low resolution. I feel like it is like that because of some non-optimal graphics providers, dependencies, or other kinds of environment configuration.

this is my first UI project and so I was hoping if someone could shed some light on this issue.
Is there a way to fix or improve it?

[curves and diagonal lines rendered poorly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Mfp.jpg)

kivy build log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\path\to\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-09-22_3.txt

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\path\to\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\path\to\Scripts\python.exe"

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 452.06'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>

[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available

[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

pip file describing environment dependencies:

```
[[source]]

name = "pypi"

url = "https://pypi.org/simple"

verify_ssl = true


[dev-packages]

pylint = "*"


[packages]

wheel = "*"

setuptools = "*"

docutils = "*"

pygments = "*"

pypiwin32 = "*"

kivy-deps-sdl2 = "==0.1.*"

kivy-deps-glew = "==0.1.*"

kivy-deps-gstreamer = "==0.1.*"

kivy = "==1.11.1"

kivy-examples = "==1.11.1"


[requires]

python_version = "3.7"
```

code to reproduce one poorly rendered graphic shape in kivy:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle

class CurvesLookBad(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """I already tried different values for segments. stil looks pretty bad."""
        super(CurvesLookBad, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            RoundedRectangle(pos= (self.x + 20, self.y + 20), size= self.size)
        

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
        return CurvesLookBad()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

the code above draws a rounded-corners rectangle on a kivy window.
those corners look as if my screen is from the 90s... :)
does it look like that on your machine as well?

Thanks in advance to all contributors!

Comment: How do you render the lines?

Comment: I use the canvas attribute of the various widgets and use kivy.graphics .Color .Rectangle .Line .RoundedRectangle .Triangle to draw the shapes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see if we get the same results.

Comment: I editted my question and added a minimal reproducible example. thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue.   Still searching for a solution.  Drawing a simple ellipse in the canvas.before section of a button for example renders a circle with jagged edges.